# R convert string date (e.g. "October 1, 2014") to Date format

Tags: r, date, date-conversion

how can I convert a vector of date string like `c("October 1, 2014", "June 14, 2014")` to a vector of R `Date` format?

I have a data.frame which one column is date string in the above format.

I would appreciate your help.

Thanks!

Comment: Use `?strptime` to get the format codes.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try:

```
v <- c("October 1, 2014", "June 14, 2014") 
as.Date(v, "%B %d,%Y")
```

Which gives:

```
#[1] "2014-10-01" "2014-06-14"
```

Or

```
strptime(v, "%B %d,%Y")
```

Which gives:

```
#[1] "2014-10-01 EDT" "2014-06-14 EDT"
```

---

**Benchmark**

```
largev <- rep(v, 10e5)

library(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark(
  as.Date = as.Date(largev, "%B %d,%Y"),
  strptime = strptime(largev, "%B %d,%Y"),
  times = 10
)
```

Which gives:

```
#Unit: seconds
#     expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval cld
#  as.Date 1.479891 1.480671 1.527838 1.483158 1.489222 1.863777    10  a 
# strptime 2.177625 2.183247 2.237732 2.255282 2.268452 2.272537    10   b
```

---

As per mentionned by @cory in the comments, use `?strptime` to get the format codes:

> - **%B** Full month name in the current locale. (Also matches    abbreviated name on input.)
> - **%d** Day of the month as decimal number (01–31).
> - **%Y** Year with century. Note that whereas there was no zero  in the    original Gregorian calendar, ISO 8601:2004 defines it to be valid (interpreted as 1BC)

Comment: Also `strptime(v, "%B %d,%Y")`

Comment: Thanks guys :) Any  difference in terms of performance between `as.Date` and `strptime`?